# AsyncTask vs Thread vs Service (communicating with server)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I'm trying to implement an android app where I can send commands to a server that controls a robot. The problem is quite "simple": I would like to keep a connection and communicate with the thread-service-task to send messages to the server, and get the responses to update UI and keep the user with the related information from the robot sensor.

So, what should be my decision? I know its probably duplicated. But I didnt find my same problem, cause I want to extend the question:

*Is there any way to run a background process on an activity, change activity and keep it going?* (Activity or fragment, I would go for fragments in the future).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for this is probably a Service.
A very good article on Services, including how to communicate with a background service via either Intents or broadcast events can be found at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Reference Code that uses an Android App , Arduino to Control a Bot. You can see its Structure thats what i have used in my robot as well. AsynkTasks wont be a good option in this aspect. Using a Service is a goodIdea for Long Running Communication

https://code.google.com/p/mover-bot/

Here is a Live Demo of This Android Controlled Robot.

[Mover Bot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsdD3CP7t_s#t=33)

Answer (score 1):

One typical model for your situation is to use:

- Service for long running communication (taking "orders" from a queue
- BroadcastReceiver to be notified about asynchronous events handled by Service
- Activity to handle UI

One reference to consider looking at is [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html#components)

Answer (score 1):

Do your work in Background and notify the result to UI thread.

Go through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) for more detailed overview.

**AsyncTask**

It is a helper class around Thread and Handler for making threading and easy for you. Just do your task in background and publish result in UI thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

**Thread**

Use basic concept of threading in java, create your own thread pool do your task and publish your result in UI thread using handler. Mainlly, used when you need more longer running task while your ui is visible (for simple background task asynctask). It will take time in implementation but provide you more control over task management.

https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html

**Service**

Services are used when you have more longer running task and also you want your ui to be independent from your task.

Here in your case i would prefer you should use a **service** for communication and use binder or broadcast manager for reflecting change in UI.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html